# I have words in a cell mixed with word I want to extract. How do I extract the words or delete the words I don't need?

Tags: pandas, excel-formula

Hello I'm looking for a solution in Pandas or excel. I have a spread sheet with a column that contain words separated by a semicolon

```
apple - slice123; banana; apple - slice321; orange; citron; apple - slice345;
```

I want to extract "banana" and "orange" and "citron" into a new column.

I looked for tokenization and pandas extract with word list but I didn't not find a solution.

My original csv contains 1058 rows and the column in question has 1 correct word (orange etc) and 1 error (apple - sliceXYZ) but also 5 correct words and up to 100 errors.

I hope someone has an idea how to solve this.

Edit for clarification.

I have 1027 rows in in the table but only the column with the data of the "fruits" is relevant. I know that I have 27 different fruits somewhere in the columns

Edit: I added a html table for clarification. The word list is used to identify the relevant "fruits" out of the column data and tells me in the results which of the fruits was used in the column data.

```html
<style>
  table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse; padding: 15px;
}
</style>



<table>
  <tr>
    <td><p><strong>Colunmn 1</strong></p></td>
    <td><p><strong>Colunmn 2</strong></p></td>
    <td><p><strong>Data</strong></p></td>
    <td><p><strong>Result</strong></p></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><p>not relevant</p></td>
    <td><p>not relevant</p></td>
    <td><p>apple - slice123; banana; apple - slice321; orange; citron; apple - slice345</p></td>
    <td><p>banana; orange; citron</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>not relevant</p></td>
    <td><p>not relevant</p></td>
    <td><p>apple - slice435; banana; apple - slice687; orange; citron; apple - slice334; mango; papaya</p></td>
    <td><p>banana; orange; citron; mango; papaya</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p></p>

<table>

  <tr>
    <td><p> <strong>word list</strong><p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>banana</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>orange<p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>citron<p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>mango<p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>papaya<p></td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

Comment: you need to be a bit more specific. Also would it be nice if you would show some data, or the desired output. `apple - slice123; banana; apple - slice321; orange; citron; apple - slice345;` <- is that one row of that column and there are 1058 of that kind ? Do you want to have the 3 fruits in 3 seperate columns or together as one new string in a new column ?

Comment: Edit in main question. Thank you

Comment: did any of the answers help your task ? please consider accepting one of them to close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can do it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Col2": ["not relevant", "not relevant"],
        "Data": [
            "apple - slice123; banana; apple - slice321; orange; citron; apple - slice345;",
            "apple - slice435; banana; apple - slice687; orange; citron; apple - slice334; mango; papaya",
        ],
    }
)
word_list = ['banana', 'orange', 'citron', 'mango', 'papaya']

two options:
a) 
df["Result"] = df["Data"].map(
    lambda s: ";".join(
        filter(None, [x.strip() for x in s.split(";") if "slice" not in x])
    )
)

b)
df["Result"] = df["Data"].map(
    lambda s: ";".join(
        filter(None, [x.strip() for x in s.split(";") if x.strip() in word_list])
    )
)

print(df['Result']

0                 banana;orange;citron
1    banana;orange;citron;mango;papaya
Name: Result, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2019 (or greater) and the first cell with data is A1 you could use

```
=TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,(FILTERXML("<c><e>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,";","</e><e>")&"</e></c>","//e[node() and not(contains(., '-'))]")))
```

If you have Excel 2013 to 2016 then you could just use the FILTERXML() portion of the above, but it would have to be entered as an array formula, e.g. select cells B1:D1, enter the formula in the formula bar, and press CTRL+Shift+Enter to confirm it
(you're selecting 3 cells because you expect to have 3 results)